# Information Theory Question about unequality

Tags: information-theory

An  advanced form of the Chappe semaphore consists of three wooden arms on top of a tower. Each arm can take one of five positions: `Full Down’,`Half Down’, `Level’,`Half Up’ and `Full Up’. An observer watches the semaphore through a telescope and notes down three consecutive positions of the three arms. What is the maximum possible information content of what he’s recorded?

I am not sure how to do this since I'm new to information theory, and I couldn't find any notes online nor has my professor supplied any. Any help would be appreciated!

I tried doing logbase(2)(4/12) since there are 12 possible outcomes and there are 4 choices, but I got it wrong the answer is slightly less than 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each arm yields $\log_2(5)$ bits of information.  The observer has seen 9 arms, with total information content $9 \log_2(5) \approx 20.90$ bits.

Comment: Sorry I'm dumb but why is it log2(5) for each arm

Comment: @JakeGinobi Assuming all 5 positions are equally likely, the probability of any position is $p=1/5$.  By definition, the information content of any position is $-\log_2(p)$.